# How do I find class prefix with multiple classes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, class, wildcard, prefix

I have span tags with multiple classes:

```
 <div class="container">
 <span class="otherclass item3">Text</span>
 <span class="otherclass item1">Blah</span>
 <span class="item2">Stuff</span>
 </div>
```

I'm interested in counting the number of span elements with the class prefixed with 'item'. I know that I can do this:

```
 $(document).on('click','span',function(){
 var ItemTot = $(this).closest('.container').find('[class*= item]').length;
 alert(ItemTot);
 }
```

... to count the number of span elements with multiple classes, but that won't count the single class span. I can get that with the code below, but surely there is a cleaner way of getting counting both cases?

```
 .find('[class^=item]').length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS lacks a "word starts with" attribute selector. (It has *attribute* starts with [`^=`], and it has word matching [`~=`], but not a *combination* of them that matches the start of a word.)

So you have to do it manually: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ozeqix/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ozeqix/1/edit)

```
var ItemTot = $(this).closest('.container').find('[class*=item]').filter(function() {
    return this.className.match(/\bitem/);
}).length;
```

That finds any element whose `class` attribute contains `item` (anywhere), and then filters based on only those where `item` is the beginning of a word.

Comment: Thank you T.J Crowder - that works! After more searching, I've found this solution also - which one works best in your opinion?:  $(this).closest('.container').find('[class^=item],[class*= item]').length;

Comment: @Jusy1: I'm not following you, which one of which? I'm not aware of any other reliable way to do this.

Comment: @Jusy1: The `^=` part (match given word) of that is redundant, anything that will match that will also match the other part, `*=` (match substring). That expression will find elements with the class `item` (so, not restricted to ones that have a digit after them) and also elements with classes like `fooitembar` (`item` not at beginning of word). So it's up to you, if those aren't an issue for you, use `*=`. If you want to be sure just to match classes in the form `itemX`, you'll need the `filter`.

Comment: Great - thanks for the clarification - your solution is the solution!

Answer (score -1):

You're cleanest option is `$('span[class~="item"]').length`

```
alert($('span[class~="item"]').length);
```

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/sPNLW/1/

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ The `$('span[class~="item"]')` finds all `spans` that contain `item` anywhere in the `class` attribute.

Comment: That won't match `<span class="otherclass item3">Text</span>` (`item` doesn't appear at teh beginning of the attribute).

Comment: I updated it, was thinking prefix, but yeah, `$('span[class^="item"]').length` is the cleanest. Why not use the APIs built in features? They are there for a reason.

Comment: I was referring to the `^=` version of your answer. Again: That won't find `<span class="otherclass item3">Text</span>`: http://jsfiddle.net/sPNLW/2/

Comment: And of course, `~=` is a bad idea as it won't match **any** `itemX` class (just `item`). If you read my answer, you'll see why you have to write code for this.